# Sizes like Height and Width with absolute differences on different displays

Tags: maui

I am working with .NET MAUI and need so set some sizes that I don't know how to realize with layouts. I currently think it is not possible, but am not sure.

```xml
<Border x:Name="InnerBorder" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleView}" SizeChanged="InnerBorder_SizeChanged">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        
        <!-- Search... -->
        <SearchBar ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal" Text="{Binding SearchText}" Placeholder="{loc:Translate SearchItemPlaceholder}"/>


        <!-- CollectionView: Margin to get the ScrollBar to the right and closer to the Border -->
        <CollectionView x:Name="InnerCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedItems, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource CollectionViewStyle}" Background="Green">

            <!-- Group Header: to group items -->
            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:GroupedItemList">
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding GroupName, StringFormat=' {0}'}" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}" />
                        <BoxView Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderUnderlineStyle}"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

            <!-- Group Items -->
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type databaseModels:Item}">

                    <SwipeView>

                        <!-- Item Name including rectangle with round corners -->
                        <Grid Padding="0, 5">
                            <Frame>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                        
                        <SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <SwipeItems>
                                <!--<SwipeItemView Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:ItemsOverviewViewModel}}, Path=DeleteItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                    <Label FontSize="12" Text="{loc:Translate ItemsOverview_SwipeItemDeleteItem}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                </SwipeItemView>-->

                                <!-- We need the suffix ..Command in the Name as it will be generated like this with the MVVM Toolkit -->
                                <SwipeItem Text="{loc:Translate ItemsOverview_SwipeItemDeleteItem}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}"
                                           Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:ItemsOverviewViewModel}}, Path=DeleteItemCommand}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>

                                <SwipeItem Text="{loc:Translate ItemsOverview_SwipeItemEditItem}" BackgroundColor="LightGrey" 
                                           Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:ItemsOverviewViewModel}}, Path=EditItemCommand}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.RightItems>                                
                    </SwipeView>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    
</Border>
```

```cs
private void InnerBorder_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var parent = sender as Border;

    InnerCollectionView.HeightRequest = parent.Height - 110;
}
```

To get the ScrollView to scroll its content it must be small enough.And in my case I need it a bit smaller than its parent.

I don't know if there are possibilities with layouts that allow me to realize that other than just reducing the parent height by 110.

Really don't like these absolute numbers, but I don't have a different idea right now. On the display size in my Emulator that is currently set up it seems to work like that, but would I get in trouble by doing it like that on different display sizes? Is there a better option?

Comment: Yes, you will get into trouble. Big time.

Comment: Not enough information to suggest what to do instead. Put into words (or pseudo-code) a formula that makes sense to you. Consider what to do when there is plenty of space vs. too little space. Factors that might affect the calculation: screen height, number of items in collection. Might end up with formulas like `Math.Max(a, Math.Min(b, c))`, where “b” is the ideal size calculation, but a,c clamp it to a reasonable range. E.g. `Max(30, Min(…, 120))`.

Comment: The Height of the parent is based on height of the display (e.g. „… * 0.7“). To me that could be the first problem. At the very bottom there is a bottom tab (an extension) and the parent should be displayed close to it. Is the resulting value from this calculation always a good one? Then the child (a view to scroll) should also get a height so that its inner elements are visible fully when scrolling or also they should be displayed in the first place, so that no inner element is cut off. When I work with an Emulator, I can display it as wanted, but even changing from iOS to Android chnge resul

Comment: @H.A.H. - from your experience, how should I deal with that? In my opinion it is difficult to work solely with layout managers if you want to realize certain effects, just like described above that the inner elements should not be cut off or that a border should be just a little bit higher than its parent or something like that. I don’t know if relative percentage values like a calculation with „… * 0.7“ always provides the same visual effect on every display size. What is your experience?

Comment: @OXO I would replace the outermost VerticalStackLayout with grid.

Comment: Okay, my intention was to have an „easier“ layout. But, I also read about the Grid it is not necessarily less performant. Would I have a benefit in my case to layout the inner parts easier and in a better way or was it just a general advise to use it?

Comment: Back to my original question: is setting a padding or a margin also considered to be dangerous or trouble-making as we deal with absolute numbers or is it more acceptable? Layouting without use of such placings gets real tricky otherwise

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you can create a method to calculate the height and width  of the device.

Here is the example code to get the information of the device.

```
     void getDeviceInfo()
        {
            // Get Metrics
            var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
            var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;
            //HEIGHT
            var height = mainDisplayInfo.Height;
            // Screen density
            var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
            Console.WriteLine("DEVICE WIDTH : " + width + " DEVICE HEIGHT :"+ height + " DEVICE DENSITY : "+ density);
    
            var mywidthrequest = (width / density) * 0.9;
            var myheightrequest = (height / density) * 0.9;
            Width = mywidthrequest;
            Height = myheightrequest;
    
        }
```

Then you can assign the percentage of the height to different components in your project.

Comment: Interesting piece of code - what do I actually calculate with use of density?

Comment: The density is the scaling or a factor that can be used to convert between physical pixels and scaled pixels. You can check this document about [DisplayInfo.Density Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.devices.displayinfo.density?view=net-maui-7.0). It use to calculate the scaled pixels in your device.

Comment: Do we really just need that for the Width only or should there actually be a similar calculation for the Height? Currently, I only care about the Height, the Width is only determined by the Layouts

Comment: Yes, we should calculate the height use the same method as the width.